# Could not Deduce Template Argument for 'TYPE'

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following code that works fine:

```
list <Politician> MakeList ( int num, ... ){
  va_list arguments;                     
  va_start ( arguments, num ); 
  list <Politician> PoliticianList;
  for ( int x = 0; x < num; x++ ) {
      PoliticianList.push_back(va_arg (arguments, Politician));
  }
  va_end ( arguments );                 

  return PoliticianList;       
}
```

However, when trying to make it generic:

```
template<class TYPE>
list <TYPE> MakeList ( int num, ... ){
  va_list arguments;                     
  va_start ( arguments, num ); 
  list <TYPE> PoliticianList;
  for ( int x = 0; x < num; x++ ) {
      PoliticianList.push_back(va_arg (arguments, TYPE));
  }
  va_end ( arguments );                 

  return PoliticianList;       
}
```

I get the following error when compiling:

```
error C2783: 'std::list<TYPE> MakeList(int,...)' : could not deduce template argument for 'TYPE'
```

How can I make it generic, so I won't have to re-implement for a different class objects?

Comment: How are you calling that function?

Comment: A variadic template would be a better option if you have C++11.

Comment: You have to say `MakeList<Foo>(3, foo1, foo2, foo3)`.

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem: [_Live Code_](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=9e7e89443086a6ca0db66426a1d605b3-83e866535a38890f283077ce45ff5373). How do you using `MakeList` ?

Comment: MakeList<Foo>(3, foo1, foo2, foo3)

Comment: MakeList<Foo>(3, foo1, foo2, foo3) solved the problem, thanks a lot guys.

Comment: By the way, it's undefined behaviour to pass anything but POD types as variable arguments.

Answer (score 3):

You need to explicitly provide a template argument for `TYPE` when invoking the templated version of `MakeList`, because the compiler doesn't know, based only on the arguments you are providing, what `TYPE` should be. For instance, given the following call:

```
MakeList<Politician>(3, politician1, politician2, politician3)
```

There is no way the compiler could deduce what `TYPE` is. If you are expecting it to be clever enough and deduce that you are passing objects of type `Politician` as arguments, well that won't work: C-style variadic functions simply do not provide that information at compile time.

However, in C++11 you could use *variadic templates* for this purpose, which among other thing would allows you *not* to pass in the number of subsequent arguments as the first argument. Here is a possible way you could rewrite your variadic `MakeList()`:

```
namespace detail
{
    template<typename T>
    void MakeList(std::list<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>& l, T&& elem)
    {
        l.push_back(std::forward<T>(elem));
    }

    template<typename T, typename... Ts>
    void MakeList(
        std::list<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>& l, 
        T&& elem, Ts&&... elems)
    {
        l.push_back(std::forward<T>(elem));
        MakeList(l, std::forward<Ts>(elems)...);
    }
}

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
std::list<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type> MakeList(
    T&& elem, Ts&&... elems)
{
    std::list<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type> l;
    detail::MakeList(l, std::forward<T>(elem), std::forward<Ts>(elems)...);
    return l;
}
```

You could then use it this way:

```
int main()
{
    Politician p1{"John", "Smith"};
    Politician p2{"Mike", "Black"};
    Politician p3{"George", "White"};

    std::list<Politician> myList = MakeList(p1, p2, p3);

    for (auto const& p : myList)
    {
        std::cout << p.name << " " << p.surname << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Here is a [**live example**](http://ideone.com/UKUS4N).